# Seedling Identification, possible weed

Tags: identification, seedlings

Following seedling grew itself, most probably a non-flowering plant without seed ? But I do recognize cotyledons.

This pot has healthy growing Jatropha plant.

**25 September 2021**

[image]

**23 September 2021 :**

[image: Today]

**15 September 2021:**

[image: One week ago]

Comment: what part of the world is this?

Comment: Karachi, Pakistan.

Comment: Most probably from the genus *Phyllanthus*, hard to say which exact species though. We'll need flowers and fruits to determine that correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This plant belongs to the genus *Phyllanthus* of the family *Phyllanthaceae*. It can be `Phyllanthus niruri` or `Phyllanthus amarus` or `Phyllanthus urinaria`, commonly known as Child Pick-A-Back, Gale Of Wind, Carry Me Seed, Stonebreaker.

It is a flowering plant, though they too tiny to spot and blooms under the leaves. So are the fruits.
[image]

That's why it is often called as seed-under-leaf also.

These plants are said to have medicinal values, though **I would not recommend to use them** as there is insufficient evidence of its safety and effectiveness due to a lack of research.

It grows easily, does not require much care, if you want to keep it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into it. I just started gardening and do not want to just pull out any plant that grew itself, specially if I know they are dicots. Its seed must have came with the air or in the soil manure mix I bought from local Nursery. Not closing this thread until it grows flowers and fruit, need seeds cuz I love germination.